# CKEditor style sheet not loading on target page

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I just implemented CKEditor into my site. However, I noticed that the `contents.css` file is not being loaded/called at all.

For example, in the editor I can highlight a word or phrase and it shows the correct yellow background. But as soon as I save the text and display it as html on my page, the yellow background is no longer there.

After inspecting the element I can see that it has been given the class of `marker`. When I look at the `contents.css` file, it shows that `marker` has a `background-color` of yellow.

Using FireBug, I can see that `contents.css` is never even loaded on the page. What do I need to change here to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contents.css` file provides styles for the content that is in the editor. You can define it with the [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) option.

Do note that the API documentation description for this setting says:

> The CSS file(s) to be used to apply style to editor content. It should reflect the CSS used in the target pages where the content is to be displayed.

CKEditor has no way of knowing what you do with the content it outputs. The default styles available in the Styles drop-down list are just examples and it's up to the developer to customize this list to match the overall look of their website and to add the appropriate styles to the target page. You can read more about it in the [Applying Styles to Editor Content](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles) documentation and see the relevant [CKEditor SDK sample](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/styles.html).

Comment: Thanks for this! I figured it had to be something similar to that, I just couldn't find the correct documentation.

Comment: Happy to help! Note that you can view/download the source code of any SDK sample (just scroll to the bottom of each sample page) if you need some inspiration :)